# How do I implement high performance 3D graphics w/ WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, gdi+

I have to develop a CAD application and I am planing to use WPF with C#. Earlier I had used GDI+ with C# to write similar application.

How can I perform the graphics operation in WPF similar to GDI+?

I want to set the pixel color with pencil (similar to MS Paint), draw some basic shapes such as circles, lines, rectangles etc etc.

I am planning to use canvas. Some one have any example?

Thanks

Comment: If you rephrase this as "How do I implement high performance 3D graphics w/ WPF" then it will be a real question.  Right now, you are asking a qualitative question: "is it good?".  A better approach would be to determine what the requirements are for this sort of thing (hardware accelerated 2D framebuffer support, hardware acceleration, 3D support, shader support, GPU code support), and asking if it supports those, and which APIs you would use to ask them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes , Wpf can be used for havey graphics based UI. See this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480192.aspx)

For performance of WPF see this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timothyc/archive/2006/06/16/634638.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Check out Kael Rowan`s [ZoomableCanvas](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/2010/07/29/zoomablecanvas.aspx). It provides Virtualization  and may be more suitable for heavy graphics scenarios than the default Canvas.